# How do I properly start creating a programming language in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I've been thinking to make a programming language written in python but I have no idea where to start, and I really don't know the steps creating it.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I don't think you want to write a programming Language in python. C or some other low-level language could be used much more resource-efficiently. If you mean make a program in python, that's a different story.

Answer (score 3):

You would probably start by first planning out your language. That should take a lot of time. Then in Python... you would write a parser that can understand the syntax of your language, and an interpreter that can take the results of the parser and perform the actions of the program.

Your language that is written in Python with Python in-turn being written in C is practically guaranteed to be very slow and will not succeed, but this could be a really fun thing to do as a learning or education experience.

Answer (score 0):

You will likely want to look at Abstract Syntax Trees.  This is the underlying structure that python is built on.  Take a look here at the documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html

Using ASTs you can at least define the syntax of your language.  You will still need to solve the problem of how to interpret it on a platform to get your code to execute.